# Get response of Node.js Express app as a string

Tags: node.js, express

How does one get the response of an express app as a string given a request object?

In other words, I want a way to send a request object to an express app and receive its response as a string.

As code, I am looking for some implementation of the `sendToThisApp` method:

```
var app = express();
app.get( /* Some code here */ );
var request = // Some request object
var response = app.sendToThisApp(req)
console.log(response);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for a simple Node.js Express app :

```
var app, express;
express = require('express');
app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(res);
    res.end();
});
app.listen(8080);
```

In order to trigger a get request on this app, you need to run the app on node. Open a terminal and type this command:

```
node app.js
```

Then, you only need to start your favorite browser, go to localhost:8080, and look back at the log of the response in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting things to happen synchronously that node and express want to handle asynchronously through callbacks.

But aside from that, I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do.

If you have the code for the node app, and you just want to see the response object as a string, then the easiest way to handle that is through the callback on the get.

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){ 
  console.log(res);
}
```

But without knowing what you're actually after, I can't give better advice.

Comment: `app.get` allows you to have the app respond when it receives a get request. What I'm looking for is a way to trigger that get request on the app and receive the response that the app would give.

Comment: So your options are to either a) externalize your handlers into classes you can instantiate and pass parameters to, or b) make a web request to the running app.  The latter is trivially easy in node, even easier than normal if you choose to use the 'request' module from npm.  In either case,  you'll still be handling it as a callback rather than doing it synchronously.

Comment: I don't mind the asynchronous behavior. Would I then make the app listen on a port, then make a request to that port? That approach seems a bit superfluous...